# How to use bibliocraft clipboard (1.7.10)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I am doing projects in modded minecraft (1.7.10) and I wanted to get an in-game to do list. So I crafted checklist! I did everything described [here](http://www.bibliocraftmod.com/wiki/clipboard/).

And it was awesome until I exited the checklist - everything I wrote in there disappeared. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to ask the community or the devs behind BiblioCraft?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I thought I would get an answer quicker here

Comment: We aren't the creators of the BiblioCraft mod though. While some of our users may play the mod, the bulk of people who care about it and consistently use it will be the BiblioCraft devs and any communities they have.